# KnockoutJS and computed property not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have just started with knockout this Model and viewmodel:

```
$(function() {

  // Class to represent a note
  function Note(title, content) {
    var self = this;

    self.title = ko.computed(function() {
  var title = title;
  if(title.length > 0) return title;

  if(self.content && self.content.length > 0) return self.content.substring(0,19) + "...";   
    });   

    self.content = ko.observable(content);

  }

  // Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
  function TaccuinoViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    // Editable data
    self.notes = ko.observableArray([
    ]);

    // Operations
    self.addNote = function() {
        self.notes.push(new Note());
    }
    self.removeNote = function(note) { self.notes.remove(note) }
  }

  ko.applyBindings(new TaccuinoViewModel());

});
```

The problem is with the computed property: what i want to do is:

1-)if title has a length > 0 use it
2-)in case it's not defined use the first 20 charachters from content + "..."

but this doens't work...

any suggestion about doing this, also in other ways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`self.content` is an observable, so you need to invoke it in order to get the current value:

```
self.content = ko.observable(content);
self.title = ko.computed(function() {
    if(title.length > 0) return title;

    var currentContent = self.content(); // <-- get the current value
    if(currentContent) return currentContent.substring(0,19) + "...";   
});
```

Note that I've moved the creation of the observable "content" to the top, because when creating a computed observable, its initial value gets computed once - so we may need the "content" observable to be present.

Comment: it works except 2 problems, I've updated the question to explain it better... thanks for now!

Comment: That behavior is just natural - whenever you edit the content, the title updates as well. You will need more tricks to get this working. To your second question: If you want to write to a computed observable, you will need to specify how that should work internally (see http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html). I restored the original question (it may help somebody else) - please open a new one if you have more questions.

Comment: Read about reand and write but still not working :( but i've opened another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323503/knockout-writing-and-reading-a-computed-property