# Knockout: writing and reading a computed property

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a model with two property: title and content and what I want to do is:

If title has a value, use it but in case it's blank use the first 20 chars + "..." from content.

This is the model:

```
       function Note(title, content) {
        var self = this;

        self.content = ko.observable(content);
        self.title = ko.computed({
          read: function(){
            if(!title){
              var content = self.content();
              if(content) return content.substring(0,19) + "...";
            }
          },
          write: function(title){
           return title;
          }
        });
       }
```

Title value gets correctly updated from content but it's impossible (for me) to get writing directly on title working..

**The only problem in RP Niemeyer answer is that i must have only on property for reading/writing, is that possible?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When creating your writeable computed observable, you will want to have a separate observable to contain the actual title.

More like:

```
function Note(title, content) {
    var self = this;

    self.content = ko.observable(content);
    self.title = ko.observable(title);

    self.displayTitle = ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            var title = self.title();
            if (!title) {
                var content = self.content();
                if (content) return content.substring(0, 19) + "...";
            }

            return title;
        },
        write: self.title
    });
}​
```

Comment: sorry but I need one property to show/write not two, is that possible?

Comment: I am not sure about your exact requirements, but there are several ways to make it seem as though there is one property.  Here is one where the real observable is private: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/LFzzq/.  Here is one where you use a sub-observable for display: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/LFzzq/3/ which will naturally drop off when you convert it to JSON to send back to the server.

Comment: my problem is that i'm going to use a div with contentEditable="true" so the input is also the output and it can't be an observable but a computed property because the title may change

Comment: Maybe you can explain your scenario a little further.  Not sure why either option wouldn't work from what you have described like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/LFzzq/4/.  Note that contenteditable requires a custom binding to work.

Comment: but in your fiddle updating the content editable doesn't update the  title.. thanks for your help!

Comment: Just tried FF, IE9, Chrome.  Once you leave the contenteditable, then the title updates.  Maybe we are not on the same page.  Let me know what you see.

Comment: my fault I'm using a binding that update after every chars is inserted and I thought it was the same... this evening i'll try and let you know!